# Does a Linux command called (h) exist?

Tags: shell, command, shell-builtin

I read in an unofficial documentation about a Linux shell command called `h`: it was mentioned together with the `help` and `man` commands, without any explanation. So I tried it on my linux terminal but it returned a "command not found". I searched something about in internet but found nothing helpful. 
Does anyone know if this command exists? And, if so, what is its syntax and how does it work?

Comment: can you tell us why you're asking, why do you think there is a `h` command and what did your own research say?

Comment: if your linux console does not refuse `h` command look at your `~/.bashrc` file for the `alias` definition

Comment: @RoVo I read it in an unofficial documentation and my shell refused that command, so I searched something about on the web without any result

Answer (score 7):

Like `ll` is a commonly defined alias for `ls -l`, [`h` is a commonly defined alias for `history` or `history <some-number>`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22alias+h+history%22), `history` being a builtin command of `csh` to display the history (the commands you've previously run), now also found in `bash`, `zsh` (same as `fc -l`), `ksh` (as a pre-defined alias for `hist -l`) `fish` and `yash` (as a pre-defined function).

Trying to dig some old examples, see [this old usenet post from 1984 for instance](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=net.unix/OhuVIkKvIV8/WGogO54bcVIJ).

If you've read it  mentioned in some documentation, the author might have had that alias in their `~/.cshrc`/`~/.bashrc`... or used systems where that alias was defined system-wide. Given that they mention the `help` command which is the name of a builtin of the `bash` shell, that might have been the shell they had in mind.

To know what `h` is in your shell, type `type h` if using a Bourne-like shell or `fish`, or `which h` if using `tcsh` or `whatis h` if using `rc`/`es`... In `csh`, see if `alias h` returns something. If they return that `h` is an alias for `history`, that alias was probably defined in one of the configuration files of your shell.

The actual syntax of `history` will vary with the shell. Look at your shell documentation for details (`info bash history` for the `bash` shell for instance).